Puppeteer - Recording a specific div
I am using puppeteer-screen-recorder. Is it possible instead of recording the entire screen, to record a particular target div? Similar to this,
const select = await page.waitForSelector(".car-container")
await select.screenshot({path:'cars.png'})

but instead of screenshot, you record.
